# Install Erlang on SUSE

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, opensuse

Anyone got a guide on how to install Erlang on openSUSE 11.4 (or similar)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to install it easily from the [official repo](http://software.opensuse.org/search?q=erlang&baseproject=openSUSE:11.4&lang=en&exclude_debug=true).  See the 1-Click install option.